# Compress a read file data direct on memory (for e-mail)

Tags: python, smtp, compression

I am written a code to send a e-mail through SMTP on Python. On some part of the code I attach some file to the e-mail body, sometimes this attachment is bigger than 25MB (or close) and I would like to compress it.

Due the serve restriction, I would to not create a zip/gz/tar/... on the folder and just compress the already read `data` to get a `compressed_data` byte stream that looks identical to a compressed read file. Is it possible?

```py
def add_attachment(file_path: str,id_value: Optional[str] = None, compress_file: Optional[bool] = False):
    '''Add an attachment or image to be used into the message.

    Parameters:
        File path
        Image id for the HTML use case.
        Compress the file.
    '''
    filename = os.path.split(file_path)[1]
    # Guess the content type based on the file's extension.
    ctype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(file_path)
    if ctype is None or encoding is not None:
        ctype = 'application/octet-stream'
    maintype, subtype = ctype.split('/', 1)
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as fp:
        file_size = os.fstat(fp.fileno()).st_size
        if file_size >= EMAIL_MAX_ATTACH_SIZE:
            compress_file = True  # Force compression.
        file_data = fp.read()
        # Compress the file before send (it is asked to or the uncompressed file size surpasses the e-mail attachment limit).
        if compress_file:
            pass #TODO
        # Get the file type.
        if maintype == 'application':
            mime_file = MIMEApplication(file_data, subtype, name=filename)
        elif maintype == 'image':
            mime_file = MIMEImage(file_data, subtype,name=filename)
        else:
            return
        # Add the ID to the attachment content.
        if id_value:
            mime_file.add_header('Content-ID', id_value)
        else:
            mime_file.add_header('Content-ID', '<' + os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + '>')
        # Add the attachment to the e-mail
        msg_root.attach(mime_file)
```

Comment: you can zip into a `BytesIO` object in memory [here](https://www.neilgrogan.com/py-bin-zip/) is a blog with an example

Comment: Thanks @Nullman, the blog was really useful.